# Does E[|X|] = |E[X]| always hold?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X$ be some random variable, does the equality $$E\left[ \left| X \right| \right] = \left| E[X] \right|$$
always holds? Here $X$ can be real and can be complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a nonzero random variable with $E[X]=0$, then $|E[X]| = 0$, but $E[|X|] > 0$.

Answer (score 3):

That is not true. Consider a random variable $X$ with $P(X=1)=1/2=P(X=-1)$.
We have $|E[X]|=0$ and $E[|X|]=1$.